# Make a Listviewitem Extension for multiple usage

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-framework-version

I would like to ask if how Can I convert my listviewitem function to an Listviewitem extension. Because I'm using it for multiple times.

Here's my current listview function

```
 private void AddToListView(Mediainfo info)
    {
        int count = LV.Items.Count + 1;

        var results = new List<ListViewItem> { new ListViewItem(new[]
        {
            count.ToString(),
            info.FullTitle,
            info.Resolution,
            info.Duration,
            info.Status,
        })};

        ListViewItem[] array = results.ToArray();

        LV.BeginUpdate();
        LV.ListViewItemSorter = null;
        LV.Items.AddRange(array);
        utils.LV_ResizeColumn(LV, 6);
        utils.LV_SelectAndFocusItem(LV);
        LV.Items[LV.Items.Count - 1].EnsureVisible();
        LV.EndUpdate();
    }
```

I want to make something like this but I don't know how.

```
    class MyListView : ListViewItem
    {

    }
```

Comment: I Suspect the difficulty you are experiencing is due to the way you are creating your ListViewItem, I would Suggest using Linq to create the array. 

`array =  results.Select(itm => new ListViewItem { Count = count.ToString(), Duration = info.Duration, FullTitle = info.FullTitle, Resolution = info.Resolution, Status = info.Status }).ToArray();`

Comment: @Retic wow tha's helpful advice/suggestion. Thank you I'll do it

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: @TaW WinForm .Net 4. Sorry I'll edit the tag